# Trying to import NetBeans Project from an older version using .forms

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm trying to import a NetBeans project from an older version (6.9.1) to the latest (8.0). I've gotten the necessary forms with a few .java files too. I try importing them from a .zip file but it tells "No NetBeans projects added" after telling me they already exist.

Please help.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the file format has changed? There is no backward compatibility guaranteed for such a a old NB version, you are coming from.

But the following should work: Import your 6.9.1 projects into 7.0.1 and export them. Then import the exported into 7.1 and export gain. Then imported the exported project (from 7.1) into 7.2 and export... (you get the idea)